# Sum by color in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to sum by color in excel, I try two codes: one for only red color and another for any color. The second does not work

```
Function SumColor(MatchColor As Range, sumRange As Range) As Double

Dim cell As Range
Dim myColor As Long
myColor = MatchColor.Cells(1,1).Interior.Color

For Each cell In sumRange
If cell.Interior.Color = myColor Then
SumColor = SumColor + cell.Value

End If

Next cell

End Function
```

Comment: How are cells colored, conditional formatting or cell format?

Comment: cell formmat , i have this code for red color onlz it works ,Function SumColor(sumRange As Range) As Double
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In sumRange
If cell.Interior.Color = 255 Then
SumColor = SumColor + cell.Value
End If
Next cell

End Function

Comment: need to init SumColor value!

Comment: how . im not a programer i just lern this code

Comment: Create 2 `variables` , say, `SumRed` and `SumOther` and use these within your `If` statemnt

Comment: Does this need to be a `function`? simplier if changed to a normal `sub`

Comment: The code ought to work - it adds up all cells whose colour matches that of the first cell in the range defined in MatchColor. Are you sure that cell is coloured the same as the target cells you want to add up?